# Attempting to run a simple widget inside my program but receive the "body_might_complete_normally" error. How can I correct this?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  // Build the whole list of todo items
  Widget _buildTodoList() {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // itemBuilder will be automatically be called as many times as it takes for the
        // list to fill up its available space, which is most likely more than the
        // number of todo items we have. So, we need to check the index is OK.
        if (index < _todoItems.length) {
          return _buildTodoItem(_todoItems[index], index);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Attempting to run a simple widget inside my program but receive the

> "body_might_complete_normally" error.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itemBuilder` only return on `(index < _todoItems.length)`, you need to make sure return widget on every case.

```dart
Widget _buildTodoList() {
  return   ListView.builder(
    itemCount:_todoItems.length, // your list length
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < _todoItems.length) {
        return _buildTodoItem(_todoItems[index], index);
      }
      return Text("default case");// if above condtions dont meet, return this
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: It solved the error, but now the screen fills up with "default case" when I am attempting to get it to only display the index regardless of how many items are on it...how would i resolve this?

Comment: also `itemCount` is missing on `ListView`

Comment: `itemCount` means how much item you like to render

Comment: Oh, i understand. It seems to work how I expected now, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)